# Automated email notifications from ArcField maps based on a specific values only

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap, arcgis-field-maps

I am working on integrating ArcGIS Online maps with MS Outlook email. The application, which is based on ArcGIS Online is called ArcField Maps. It uses all the fields and their data (values) to build and manipulate forms.
My goal is to integrate these forms with MS Outlook at some point, but I need just the specific data value for it.
So far I've managed well with this integration via the third-party tool - Integromat by watching this very transparent YT tutorial, which is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PM5evdCagR4&ab_channel=ArcGIS

At the stage of customizing my data criteria I've found, that I am able to set up the notification (Flow Control) only for the specific field, which looks like this:

[image]

I can use just the following field, but the email will be sent anytime regardless the value selected.
When I specify the value I need (D-pole) in the following manner:
  or = D-pole or ='D-pole' it doesn't work unfortunately. The script stops or returns other values. If I, for instance, specify 4 poles, from which for example, the 4th one is marked as D-Pole I see an email coming with the first or second one instead.
The other values and questions are listed below.

[image]

Is there any way of specifying the automated email notification based on a certain field value?

Comment: I've added it, thanks. Moreover, I've attached the YT video, which shows exactly the process. If you think, that this platform isn't the best for a question such as this? Could you tell me, where should I seek help? Thank you in advance

Comment: This question is basically a "how do I do this in Make (formally Integromat)"? Specifically "how do I look up the value and make a conditional decision" GIS SE might not be the best fit for this question; although, I'm not sure exactly what SE site would be more appropriate.

Comment: @KHibma Sor do I, therefore I decided to put this question here as it's most GIS-related.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
In this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHzNVMqC5LY

it's clearly shown, that we can use the filters

[image]

Each element is linked and right below we can see the screwing key icon indicating the settings.
Next we can set a filter
[image]